# GPS functionality from the SDK

Tags: android, uwp, gps, dji-sdk

I've read through the SDK documentation for both Windows and Android and found some functions for accessing the state of the current GPS connection and Latitude/longitude information.

I am looking to develop an application that uses 3d photogrammatry to monitor a set area in real time and am worried that built-in localization might not update the model accurately enough.

So I am wondering if there is a way to get the lower-level information like connection strength and specific connected satellites. (to compare to GPS information from the ground for better accuracy.) Is this supported? (maybe in specific drones?) Or is my only option to attatch a GPS device to it that I then access seperately?

I also know that DJI offers a drone with GPS-RTK to give this accuracy but I'm looking at alternative approaches because of the big step up in cost.

Any information / suggestions would be of great help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to report but there is no access to the raw data from the GPS sensors.  The information you found in the SDK documentation is all that is available.

How accurate are you looking for?  Generally the accuracy is pretty close, certainly within 1 foot or so and there is specifications for GPS accuracy in specific drone's manuals.

Comment: I am not sure. Whatever accuracy is needed to monitor a 3d model in which new objects can be identified. I thought < 10cm (1/3 ft.) accuracy is a must to create a usable model. I will be doing a first test with an entry level model, see if it is enough and go from there. Compatible models hook into the same SDK functions so the code will be the same regardless of what hardware I use right?

Comment: Most aircraft are pretty much the same as far as accuracy and remember, you can also use the camera specs to help.  In affect, the camera F-rating creates a virtual triangle, with the object's surface being the base.  It's imperfect, but combined with other measurements might create acceptable imagery without going to the significantly more expensive aircraft like the M210.

Comment: I will try such an approach. The idea will be to buy a cheap model, see how good the localization is with GPS, and enhance it with camera data on top of that. Using structure from motion SLAM. Alternatively I thought that with 2 drones I could combine their perspectives into a stereo vision input. To get the stitching with that right might be a challenge on its own though... The initial mapping will be rough but after some passes it might recognize enough structure to localize against. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any more info you can get from the sdk.
I guess you looking for raw meassurements? There is nothing that points to that's possible,  even in the dumledore messages.

You better stick with the newer drones, since they seems to use dual freq gps, starting from mini2. Very accurate.

Havn't tried the mavic3 but my guess is that they switched to the same gps-chip as in the mini2.

Ne aware that gps lat/lon you get is actually fused with the imu.